# regex exclude Adobe Acrobat DC version

Tags: regex

I want my Regex to match Adobe reader with patterns of `^Adobe (Acrobat )?Reader.*$`
like

```
Adobe Acrobat Reader X (11.0.10) or
Adobe Acrobat Reader XI V1.345 or
```

But not the DC version with pattern `\bDC\b` after Adobe Acrobat Reader, e.g.,:

```
Adobe Acrobat Reader DC MUI
```

How should I make my current regex `^Adobe (Acrobat )?Reader.*$` to exclude pattern of `\bDC\b`?

Answer (score 0):

Put a negative lookahead before the point to expect "DC":

```
^Adobe (?!.*DC)(Acrobat )?Reader.*$
```

This will not match is "DC" appears anywhere after the lookahead.